# iTunes Song Title Scrolling in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, itunes, nstextfield, nsscrollview

I have searched extensively and cannot for the life of me find any information about how to achieve a similar effect to that of the iTunes song title scrolling if the text is too large in Cocoa. I have tried setting the bounds on a NSTextField to no avail.  I have tried using NSTextView as well as various attempts at using NSScrollView.  I am sure I am missing something simple but any help would be greatly appreciated. I am also hoping to not have to use CoreGraphics if at all possible.

[Example](http://cybernetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/itunes-streaming-radio-1.png), notice the "Base.FM http://www." text has been scrolled. If you need a better example open iTunes with a song with a rather large title and watch it scroll back and forth.

I would think surely there is a simple way to just create a marquee type effect with an NSTextField and an NSTimer, but alas.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can see how this would be difficult if you're trying to shoehorn the functionality into an exist control.  However, if you just start with a plain NSView, it's not that bad.  I whipped this up in about 10 minutes...

```
//ScrollingTextView.h:
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface ScrollingTextView : NSView {
    NSTimer * scroller;
    NSPoint point;
    NSString * text;
    NSTimeInterval speed;
    CGFloat stringWidth;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * text;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval speed;

@end


//ScrollingTextView.m

#import "ScrollingTextView.h"

@implementation ScrollingTextView

@synthesize text;
@synthesize speed;

- (void) dealloc {
    [text release];
    [scroller invalidate];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) setText:(NSString *)newText {
    [text release];
    text = [newText copy];
    point = NSZeroPoint;

    stringWidth = [newText sizeWithAttributes:nil].width;

    if (scroller == nil && speed > 0 && text != nil) {
        scroller = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:speed target:self selector:@selector(moveText:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (void) setSpeed:(NSTimeInterval)newSpeed {
    if (newSpeed != speed) {
        speed = newSpeed;

        [scroller invalidate];
        scroller == nil;
        if (speed > 0 && text != nil) {
            scroller = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:speed target:self selector:@selector(moveText:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        }
    }
}

- (void) moveText:(NSTimer *)timer {
    point.x = point.x - 1.0f;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    // Drawing code here.

    if (point.x + stringWidth < 0) {
        point.x += dirtyRect.size.width;
    }

    [text drawAtPoint:point withAttributes:nil];

    if (point.x < 0) {
        NSPoint otherPoint = point;
        otherPoint.x += dirtyRect.size.width;
        [text drawAtPoint:otherPoint withAttributes:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

Just drag an NSView onto your window in Interface Builder and change its class to "ScrollingTextView".  Then (in code), you do:

```
[myScrollingTextView setText:@"This is the text I want to scroll"];
[myScrollingTextView setSpeed:0.01]; //redraws every 1/100th of a second
```

This is obviously pretty rudimentary, but it does the wrap around stuff that you're looking for and is a decent place to start.

Comment: Works like a champ.  I can't believe I couldn't find any similar examples on the internet.  Maybe it is just too simple now that I see your solution.

Comment: Thats probably because its kind of a UI anti-pattern. For a few reasons the chief is that at any given time if the user looks at it, is it going to be showing the information that they want? Probably not.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this in Swift 4, I have converted Dave's answer and added some more functionality.

```
import Cocoa

open class ScrollingTextView: NSView {
    /// Text to scroll
    open var text: NSString?

    /// Font for scrolling text
    open var font: NSFont?

    /// Scrolling text color
    open var textColor: NSColor = .headerTextColor

    /// Determines if the text should be delayed before starting scroll
    open var isDelayed: Bool = true

    /// Spacing between the tail and head of the scrolling text
    open var spacing: CGFloat = 20

    /// Amount of time the text is delayed before scrolling
    open var delay: TimeInterval = 2 {
        didSet {
            updateTraits()
        }
    }

    /// Length of the scrolling text view
    open var length: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            updateTraits()
        }
    }

    /// Speed at which the text scrolls. This number is divided by 100.
    open var speed: Double = 4 {
        didSet {
            updateTraits()
        }
    }

    private var timer: Timer?
    private var point = NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    private var timeInterval: TimeInterval?

    private(set) var stringSize = NSSize(width: 0, height: 0) {
        didSet {
            point.x = 0
        }
    }

    private var timerSpeed: Double? {
        return speed / 100
    }

    private lazy var textFontAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = {
        return [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font ?? NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]
    }()

    /**
     Sets up the scrolling text view
     - Parameters:
     - string: The string that will be used as the text in the view
     */
    open func setup(string: String) {
        text = string as NSString
        stringSize = text?.size(withAttributes: textFontAttributes) ?? NSSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        setNeedsDisplay(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
        updateTraits()
    }
}

private extension ScrollingTextView {
    func setSpeed(newInterval: TimeInterval) {
        clearTimer()
        timeInterval = newInterval

        guard let timeInterval = timeInterval else { return }
        if timer == nil, timeInterval > 0.0, text != nil {
            if #available(OSX 10.12, *) {
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: newInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(update(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

                guard let timer = timer else { return }
                RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        } else {
            clearTimer()
            point.x = 0
        }
    }

    func updateTraits() {
        clearTimer()

        if stringSize.width > length {
            guard let speed = timerSpeed else { return }
            if #available(OSX 10.12, *), isDelayed {
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delay, repeats: false, block: { [weak self] timer in
                    self?.setSpeed(newInterval: speed)
                })
            } else {
                setSpeed(newInterval: speed)
            }
        } else {
            setSpeed(newInterval: 0.0)
        }
    }

    func clearTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    @objc
    func update(_ sender: Timer) {
        point.x = point.x - 1
        setNeedsDisplay(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
    }
}

extension ScrollingTextView {
    override open func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        if point.x + stringSize.width < 0 {
            point.x += stringSize.width + spacing
        }

        textFontAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = textColor
        text?.draw(at: point, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

        if point.x < 0 {
            var otherPoint = point
            otherPoint.x += stringSize.width + spacing
            text?.draw(at: otherPoint, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
        }
    }

    override open func layout() {
        super.layout()
        point.y = (frame.height - stringSize.height) / 2
    }
}
```

Reference gist:
https://gist.github.com/NicholasBellucci/b5e9d31c47f335c36aa043f5f39eedb2