# Scrolling NSString in NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstring, nsview

I'm using the method posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232801/itunes-song-title-scrolling-in-cocoa) to scroll an `NSString` across the screen. However, as shown in the image below, the string doesn't seem to be drawing correctly. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

[image]

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I modified the scrolling text class to use an attributed string rather than a regular string.

EDIT 2: I think the problem is that the string is repeating before it can finish the first time. How can I add some spacing before the string repeats itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to change this line in `drawRect:`:

```
otherPoint.x += dirtyRect.size.width;
```

to

```
otherPoint.x += (stringWidth + 20.0);
```

EDIT: You can change `20.0` depending on how much of a gap you want before the string repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the area before drawing by adding

```
NSRectFillUsingOperation(dirtyRect, NSCompositeClear);
```

at the beginning of `drawRect:`.

Comment: When I add that it makes the view completely filled black

Comment: You don't need to set the drawing color when using `NSCompositeClear`. That operation doesn't use the drawing color; it always wipes the entire affected area.

Comment: @edc1591: Did you override `isOpaque` to return `YES`? If so, you aren't allowed to leave any part of the view unpainted (or cleared). If not, are you using spudwaffle's code unmodified? If you just use `NSRectFill(dirtyRect)`, that will fill with the current color using `NSCompositeCopy`; you want `NSCompositeClear`, which erases.

Comment: No, I didn't override `isOpaque`. Should I? I just used spudwafflle's code unmodified.

Comment: @edc1591: Like I said, if you override `isOpaque` and return `YES`, then you aren't allowed to leave any part of the view cleared.

Comment: Still, all I get is a black box. Overriding `isOpaque` doesn't fix it either.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using an attributed string rather than a regular string. It looks like what's happening is the text is repeating before it ends, so it overlaps.